# specflow identifer expected error

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, gherkin

after generate step definitions, i have a problem with build solution.
There is an error "Identifier expected" with code CS10001 for feature file on THEN line

Here is feature file

```
Feature: Contact
In order to contact with customer service
As an application user
I want to send a message to them

 Background: 
Given I am on Contact us page

Scenario Outline: Sending message with invalid/empty email adress
Given I enter '<email>' adress 
And I enter '<message>' 
When I click Send
Then Email field '<validation>' appears 

Examples: 

| email                |  | message     |     validation         |
| testemail@gmaill.com |  | testMessage | Invalid email address. |
```

Here is the code

```
public class ContactSteps
    {
        [Given(@"I am on Contact us page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnContactUsPage()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [Given(@"I enter '(.*)' adress")]
        public void GivenIEnterAdress(string p0)
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [Given(@"I enter '(.*)'")]
        public void GivenIEnter(string p0)
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [When(@"I click Send")]
        public void WhenIClickSend()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [Then(@"Email field '(.*)' appears")]
        public void ThenEmailFieldAppears(string p0)
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
    }
```

After build solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjXfM.png)

Edit:

Here is this feature code behind - maybe here is the source of the problem

```
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "2.2.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [TechTalk.SpecRun.FeatureAttribute("Contact", Description="\tIn order to contact with customer service\r\n\tAs an application user\r\n\tI want to s" +
        "end a message to them", SourceFile="Features\\Contact.feature", SourceLine=0)]
    public partial class ContactFeature
    {

        private TechTalk.SpecFlow.ITestRunner testRunner;

#line 1 "Contact.feature"
#line hidden

        [TechTalk.SpecRun.FeatureInitialize()]
        public virtual void FeatureSetup()
        {
            testRunner = TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner();
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo featureInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "Contact", "\tIn order to contact with customer service\r\n\tAs an application user\r\n\tI want to s" +
                    "end a message to them", ProgrammingLanguage.CSharp, ((string[])(null)));
            testRunner.OnFeatureStart(featureInfo);
        }

        [TechTalk.SpecRun.FeatureCleanup()]
        public virtual void FeatureTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnFeatureEnd();
            testRunner = null;
        }

        public virtual void TestInitialize()
        {
        }

        [TechTalk.SpecRun.ScenarioCleanup()]
        public virtual void ScenarioTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioEnd();
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioSetup(TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioStart(scenarioInfo);
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioCleanup()
        {
            testRunner.CollectScenarioErrors();
        }

        public virtual void FeatureBackground()
        {
#line 6
#line 7
testRunner.Given("I am on Contact us page", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
#line hidden
        }

        public virtual void SendingMessageWithInvalidEmptyEmailAdress(string email, string , string message, string validation, string[] exampleTags)
        {
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo("Sending message with invalid/empty email adress", exampleTags);
#line 9
 this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
#line 6
this.FeatureBackground();
#line 10
 testRunner.Given(string.Format("I enter \'{0}\' adress", email), ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
#line 11
 testRunner.And(string.Format("I enter \'{0}\'", message), ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
#line 12
 testRunner.When("I click Send", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");
#line 13
 testRunner.Then(string.Format("Email field \'{0}\' appears", validation), ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");
#line hidden
            this.ScenarioCleanup();
        }

        [TechTalk.SpecRun.ScenarioAttribute("Sending message with invalid/empty email adress, testemail@gmail", SourceLine=17)]
        public virtual void SendingMessageWithInvalidEmptyEmailAdress_TestemailGmail()
        {
#line 9
 this.SendingMessageWithInvalidEmptyEmailAdress("testemail@gmail", "", "testMessage", "Invalid email address.", ((string[])(null)));
#line hidden
        }

        [TechTalk.SpecRun.TestRunCleanup()]
        public virtual void TestRunCleanup()
        {
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner().OnTestRunEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Screenshot from feature file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKgDW.png)

Edit:

Screenshot from error list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W9XJ.png)

Comment: The error is probably in the code behind of the feature file. If you have a look at it, you will probably see the error.

Comment: BTW, you are missing the [Binding] attribute on your class with the steps.

Comment: BInding is there, i just didn't copy it here

Comment: I added feature's behind code

Comment: Does VS not show any error in the code behind file?

Comment: There is no error in the code behind

Comment: In your second example column is no header. Did you removed it for Stack Overflow? Every column needs a header.

Comment: I added screenshot from feature file

Answer (score 2):

I see your problem. You have an empty column in your specflow examples. Meaning there is no identifier here.

So change:

```
| email                |  | message     |     validation         |
| testemail@gmaill.com |  | testMessage | Invalid email address. |
```

To:

```
| email                | message     |     validation         |
| testemail@gmaill.com | testMessage | Invalid email address. |
```